# How can I use classes to object which are not on the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop

I'm having a problem by using classes. I used this tutorial online:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALqGYMsRWxw

My problem is in this tutorial he is using objects on the stage. What I want to do is add the object from out of code and use this exact same code. So that the stage is empty and when you run the project it will add the objects which you can drag.

`Game.as` (this is where import my class)

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    import classes.tools.Tools;
    import classes.tools.ToolType1;

    public class Game extends MovieClip
    {       
        var tool1:classes.tools.ToolType1 = new classes.tools.ToolType1();

        public function Game()
        {           
            addChild(tool1);

        }
    }
}
```

`Tools` (this is what is called DraggableShirt in the tutorial)

```
package classes.tools
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Tools extends MovieClip
    {           
        var originalPosition:Point;

        public function Tools()
        {           
            originalPosition = new Point(x,y);
            buttonMode = true;
            parent.addChild(this);

            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);

        }
        // als je de muis indrukt dan pak je een voorwerp op
        function drag(evnt:MouseEvent):void
        {       
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
            this.startDrag();
            //scaling
            this.scaleY = 1.5;
            this.scaleX = 1.5;
        }
        // als je de muis loslaat laat je het voorwerp los
        function drop(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //positioning van de tools
            //Delete knop

            //bewerk knop
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
            stopDrag()  

            if(dropTarget)
            {
                if(dropTarget.parent.name == "trash")
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    returnToOriginalPosition();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                returnToOriginalPosition();
            }           
        }
        function returnToOriginalPosition():void
        {
            x = originalPosition.x;
            y = originalPosition.y;
            this.scaleX = 1;
            this.scaleY = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

`ToolType1` (this is what is called WhiteShirt/BlackShirt in the tutorial)

```
package classes.tools
{
    public class ToolType1 extends Tools
    {   
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to add it with addChild in a different class called Game.as where I import the Tools.as (which in tutorial is called DraggableShirt) (I tried to add code in my question but it isnt working with the code button somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a quick look at video 1 of 3, i'd say you already get that.
He just places his stuff on the stage for easy testing/showing.

What your looking for is code along the lines of;

```
var WhiteShirt:Class = getDefinitionByName('WhiteShirt') as Class;
var myShirt:WhiteShirt = new WhiteShirt();
myShirt.x = 100;
myShirt.y = 200;
addChild(myShirt);
```

Im not sure if you will need the first line, its something i used a while ago when i was using Classes with strings i sent back and forth between swfs, try see if it works without, else just keep it. (note that this code should go in the fla file, or even better a 'Main.as' file attached to the fla file)

Comment: should I use AS linkage as in the tutorial or just give it a name like WhiteShirt?

Comment: When I use the getDefinitionByName that way placing it in my Game class I get errors : 1180 and 1046

Comment: `var ToolType1:Class = getDefinitionByName("classes.tools.ToolType1") as Class;
  var myTool:MovieClip = new ToolType1() as MovieClip;` that is what I used to get the errors gone but now it refers problem in my Tools class like the normal addChild way adding the class because the class has no object to response to without the object added on the stage

Comment: I fixed the problem in the tools class I had to remove parent.addChild and add it to my game class now it works fine thanks for your help

Comment: Sry for not replying, was 'off the grid' for a few days, good to hear you solved it either way!! :)

Comment: Oh and yea, my mistake, i didnt really see the 'parent.addChild(this);' part, that will never work, because if its not the child of something, theres no parent. and to become the child of something, you need to do something.addChild(..) wich would create quite the bizzare loop of never ending addChilds.